# Memory usage, SortedList vs List problem

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory, collections

I was using SortedList() in a class which stores about 15-100K data.

Recently my requirements changed, data should not be stored as sorted any more so I switched to List().

However in this case I noticed that List() consumes about  20%+ more memory.

**9K items:**

- SortedList: 105MB
- List: 125MB

**15K items:**

- SortedList: 115MB
- List: 140MB

In the environment I develop, memory is quite crucial. Instead of List() what can I use to avoid this extra memory consumption and still have a non-sorted list?

*P.S. I do use a HashSet(Of String) to provide uniqueness check while using List(Of) to simulate SortedList.ContainsKey() although I don't think it can bring such memory overhead.*

*P.S. 2: My app has got about 80 MB base memory allocation in the startup. So numbers should read as 105-80=25, 125-80 =45 and so on*

**RESULTS**

Thanks for the all answers, final results are:

- You should set the correct capacity to save memory
- Hashset is very bad about memory, and consumes way more than expectations. This was the problem. Somehow SortedList() manages to use less memory for a similar functionality.

**Some Bencmarks:**
500 chars, 250000 insert

**List(OF STring)(50000)**

274 ms - 226 MB

**SortedList(Of String, String)(50000)**

34868 ms - 230 Mb

**Hashset**

420 ms - 232 MB

**Dictionary(OF String, Object)**

486 ms - 234 MB

Although when I changed decreased count to 25, then:

**Hashset** for 600.000 iteration 300 Mb where **List()** is 286 Mb

Also about Hashset memory usage: http://blog.mischel.com/2008/04/09/hashset-limitations/ Dictionary(Of string, object) was not much better either in my test.

Comment: Where did you get those values from?

Comment: From my test application, although memory should that memory - app's base memory (which is about 80MB).

Comment: From Task Manager (or similar)? Try using a profiler (like CLRProfiler: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=86ce6052-d7f4-4aeb-9b7a-94635beebdda). Memory data from Task Manager depends on garbage collection behavior.

Comment: I'd expect that memory footprint of List<T>() is about "sizeof(T)" * Capacity of list (which can be checked). If T is a class, than you are just storing references, so I'd expect, that actual footprint of your list is minimal (15k items * 4 bytes), maybe there's something else that has changed, that has more to the data itself?

Comment: Ignore my last comment if that data came from a profiler...

Comment: @Ravadre: actually, since List is array-based, there are always empty slots in it, so you can expect anything from 15k*(reference size) to 30k*(reference size).

Comment: @Martinho these numbers are consistent and not just one time reports. It's running for 5 minutes or so. So I can steadily watch the grow and compare.

Comment: @Martinho: That's why I've mentioned Capacity, not Length, as Capacity gives you the amount of such slots, that is allocated by the List<T>, not the number of elements. Therefore, it's still Capacity * 15k :)

Comment: @Ravadre it's references. SortedList() also got string keys. But the List() uses HashSet() to store the same string keys.

Comment: @Ravadre Data is exactly same, I'm just changing my class inheritance from SortedList() to List() and memory goes up.

Comment: @dr. evil - And what happens if you will throw uut hash set, just keep List? List<T> is actually an array under the hood (as Martinho said), So even if you are allocating space for 300k elements, it's still about 1.2MB only (2.4MB on 64-bit), so the list itself just can not consume much memory. The data or other structures, like hash sets have to

Comment: I can remove the hashset but doens't matter since instead of hashset the very same string will be stored as hash as SortedList's key. So wither wat it's same data stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `List<T>` with 9k items would have a capacity between 9k and 18k, so the overhead for those items would be between 36 and 72 kilobyte (the double on a 64 bit system).

Clearly the 72 kB is not even close to the 20 MB difference that you see, so the memory use of the list itself can not be the cause. Escpecially considering that the sorted list also has to keep a reference to each object, so the memory usage should be the same.

So, either there is something else using memory, or you are not looking at the actual memory usage of the application. If you are looking in the task manager, you are not seeing how much memory is used, only how much the memory manager has allocated.

Answer (score 9):

Are you preallocating the `List<T>` capacity?

Small experiment that I did:

This program takes ~640MB

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(0);

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}
```

This program takes ~320MB

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(100000000);

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: +1 This is an excellent observation because a preallocated list will grab a contiguous block of RAM at once if it can and reduce the overhead generated by memory fragmentation.

Comment: Very good point, I'll give it a try now. Doesn't the same problem exist for SortedList() ?

Comment: All containers that have the “capacity” property needs it to be set for optimal performance.

Comment: What I'm trying to say this should be irrelevant in this comparison case since I'm comparing SortedList() and List() and did not preallocate neither of them.

Comment: List<T> is also optimized to store everything in one continues block, I don't know how SortedList<T> is implemented. You will have to check it for your self. don't forget to report the results :)

Comment: I'll let you know, BTW capacity makes a HUGE difference, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Apparently problem was actually happening because of Hashset() it's using enormous amount of memory. Now I need to find a better data type to store this unique keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a HashSet of your collection, I'm not sure why you need a List as well, but if you looking for a container that guarantees uniqueness and ContainsKey() functionality, why not a generic Dictionary?

Regardless of your decision on the questions above, using something like the Task Manager is just too inaccurate to make decisions about memory consumption in .NET.  If you've not already done so, grab a trial of [SciTech's .NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) or [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm?gclid=CPi34IT4o50CFVVj2godijiprw) and run your app.  Take a snapshot of your memory usage just before loading up your set and just after to compare.  You can do this with several collection types to measure the relative memory usage of each in a highly accurate way.

Comment: +1 for recommending the use of a profiler to get accurate data.

Answer (score 1):

Hashsets (& hashtables) use a lot of memory ! Much more than a simple list/sortedlist

Comment: A Dictionary uses twice as much memory internally as a List (50% more on a 64 bit system), so the difference isn't that big.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly 50%. Hashtables are never 100 % full, they are re-sized when they reach 70%. Lists are only resized when the they are completely full.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Power Collections by Wintellect, the .NET equivalent for STL type collections. I believe the Set type should give you the functionality you need(uniqueness) but you'd have to do the benchmarks for comparison. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at glazed lists (http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/). These are very quick for sorting and are great with memory.